# Adding static Directions/Save panel using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add a "static" panel on the top left of my map (like the image below)? I am using `google.maps.Marker()` to render a marker on the map and upon clicking the Marker the panel should update with the place. I've seen it in several sites, so I'm wondering if it's possible to do using the Maps API. I've tried looking through a bunch of things (including `CustomSaveWidget`) though it is not the same thing.

[image]

Comment: duplicate of [Displaying address box in Google Maps Javascript API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565226/displaying-address-box-in-google-maps-javascript-api)

Comment: That "panel" is part of the [embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide), if you want it on a google maps javascript API v3 page, you need to code it (all the information is available through various services, but it isn't "built in")

Comment: That seems odd since it's a very distinguishable thing, probably because a lot of sites embed the map instead. Anyway, thanks for the heads up.